# OAM Registration failed with oracle forms and reports 11g R2

Tags: forms, oracle, report, single-sign-on, oam

I have installed oracle forms 11g and i configured sso with oracle identity manager 11g R1.
in the first installation and configuration it finalized with succes. 
I have reconfigured the forms and reports, and this time it failed in oam registration step.

This is the out logs error:

```html
Welcome to OAM Remote Registration Tool!
Parameters passed to the registration tool are: 
Mode: inband
Filename: C:\oracle\applicationServ\Oracle_FRHome1\oam\server\rreg\client\input\OSSORequest.xml
Enter admin username:Username: weblogic
Enter admin password:          Enter admin password:22 avr. 2015 16:10:17 oracle.security.am.engines.rreg.client.handlers.request.OSSORequestHandler validateAgentBaseURL
INFO: Fully qualified host name is required: applicationTest
agentBaseURL is invalid : http://applicationTest:8888
22 avr. 2015 16:10:17 oracle.security.am.engines.rreg.client.handlers.request.OSSORequestHandler handleRequest
INFO: URL is invalid : http://applicationTest:8888
The remote registration process did not succeed! Please find the specific error message below.
agentBaseURL is invalid.
22 avr. 2015 16:10:17 oracle.security.am.engines.rreg.client.RegClient main
GRAVE: Exception encountered: RemoteAgentRegistrationException. Specific exception:agentBaseURL is invalid.oracle.security.am.engines.rreg.common.RemoteAgentRegistrationException: agentBaseURL is invalid.
Exit Status: 1
OAM Registration failed.
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide fully qualified Host Name for applicationtest.

> Welcome to OAM Remote Registration Tool! Parameters passed to the
>   registration tool are:  Mode: inband Filename:
>   C:\oracle\applicationServ\Oracle_FRHome1\oam\server\rreg\client\input\OSSORequest.xml
>   Enter admin username:Username: weblogic
>   Enter admin password:
>   Enter admin
>   password:22 avr. 2015 16:10:17
>   oracle.security.am.engines.rreg.client.handlers.request.OSSORequestHandler
>   validateAgentBaseURL
>
> **INFO: Fully qualified host name is required: applicationTest agentBaseURL is invalid : http://applicationTest:8888** 22 avr. 2015
>
> 16:10:17
>   oracle.security.am.engines.rreg.client.handlers.request.OSSORequestHandler
>   handleRequest INFO: URL is invalid : http://applicationTest:8888 The
>   remote registration process did not succeed! Please find the specific
>   error message below. agentBaseURL is invalid. 22 avr. 2015 16:10:17
>   oracle.security.am.engines.rreg.client.RegClient main GRAVE: Exception
>   encountered: RemoteAgentRegistrationException. Specific
>   exception:agentBaseURL is
>   invalid.oracle.security.am.engines.rreg.common.RemoteAgentRegistrationException:
>   agentBaseURL is invalid. Exit Status: 1 OAM Registration failed.